# Sample project plugin jquery File Upload plugin implemented in ASP .NET MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, plugins, file-upload, sample

I need to implement in my project ASP .NET MVC3 the jQuery file upload plugin:

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

I have been Googling and I haven't found a whole project, only pieces of code. I don't know how to implement it.

Can someone help me? Can someone tell me where I can download a sample project or code?

Comment: Take a look on Telerik MVC Upload component http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload It's very well-documented and, for sure, it's working. Telerik MVC controls are open source.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've created a [sample ASP.NET MVC 3 project on GitHub](https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3) that shows how to use a full plug-in functionality, including deletion and download.

Answer (score 46):

Did you read the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) of the plugin that you are trying to use? Did you try the [basic plugin functionality](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin)? Did you try to create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application in Visual Studio using the default template?

Did you try writing a simple controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(filename);
        }
        return Json(files.Select(x => new { name = x.FileName }));
    }
}
```

and a corresponding view:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/blueimp/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/blueimp/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/blueimp/js/jquery.fileupload.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '@Url.Action("index")',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                });
            } 
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple"/>
```

If you haven't, I invite you to do so.

Comment: I have read the documentation, but there are many examples which work in a different way. For this i needed a clear example to start. Thank you, @darin

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: not to hijack this thread but could you provide some guidance on a similar thread, http://bit.ly/HMkiWx in regards to routing on the post back?  Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 18.168 answers as of now. You must be kidding, I mean, you must have clones of yourself doing the heavy lifting... You're close o Skeet. :D hehehe. Thanks again and again and again Darin for the incredible amount of help.