# Ajax FileUpload & JQuery formData in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have some problem with posting `formData` to server side action method. Because ajax call doesn't send files to server, I have to add file uploader data to `formData` manually like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("imageFile", $("#imageFile").file);
formData.append("coverFile", $("#coverFile").file);
```

I wrote jQuery function that need to post form data to server using ajax call.
It's works but posted `formData` in server side is always null!

this is my script:

```
    <script>
        function SubmitButtonOnclick()
        {    
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("imageFile", $("#imageFile").file);
            formData.append("coverFile", $("#coverFile").file);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("EditProfile", "Profile")',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "multipart/form-data",
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#GeneralSection').html(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    $('#GeneralSection').html(error.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**Edit 1:**
This is the action method in controller:

```
        public ActionResult EditProfile(ProfileGeneralDescription editedModel,
                                HttpPostedFileBase imageFile,
                                HttpPostedFileBase coverFile,
                                string postOwnerUser)
        {
            try
            {
                if (postOwnerUser == User.Identity.Name)
                {
                // edit codes...    
                    var result = GetProfileGeneralDescription(postOwnerUser);
                    return PartialView("_GeneralProfile", result);
                }
                else
                {
                    var error = new HandleErrorInfo(
                    new Exception("Access Denied!"),
                    "Profile",
                    EditProfile
                    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml", error);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var error = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "Profile", EditProfile
                return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml", error);
            }
        }
```

**Edit 2:**
Cshtml view file content:

```
@model Website.Models.ViewModel.Profile

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditProfile", "Profile", new { postOwnerUser = User.Identity.Name }, new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "GeneralSection"
    }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {

        <div>
             <button id="btnSubmit" type="button" onclick="SubmitButtonOnclick()">Submit</button>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="@Model.Username"/>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit Photos</legend>
            <div>
                Select profile picture:
                <input id="imageFile" type="file" name="imageFile" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.DefaultCover)<span>Remove profile photo</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                Select cover picture:
                <input id="coverFile" type="file" name="coverFile" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.DefaultCover)<span>RemoveCover</span>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

Any tips, link or code example would be useful.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting `contentType` to `false`?

Comment: Yes, But steel sent null to server.

Comment: [Ajax Multiple File Upload Script With Progress Bar, Drag And Drop Qq.FileUploader In Mvc 4 Razor](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2012/09/ajax-multiple-file-upload-script-with.html)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of Jquery Ajax you could use

```
 <script>
            function SubmitButtonOnclick()
            { 
                var formData= new FormData();
                var imagefile=document.getElementById("imageFile").files[0];
                var coverfile=document.getElementById("coverFile").files[0];
                formData.append("imageFile",imageFile);
                formData.append("coverFile",coverFile);
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "/Profile/EditProfile", true);
                xhr.addEventListener("load", function (evt) { UploadComplete(evt); }, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("error", function (evt) { UploadFailed(evt); }, false);
                xhr.send(formData);

            }

      function UploadComplete(evt) {
        if (evt.target.status == 200) 
                alert("Logo uploaded successfully.");

        else 
                 alert("Error Uploading File");
        }

    function UploadFailed(evt) {
        alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");

    }
 </script>
```

This works for me !!

Your script  with changes

```
 function SubmitButtonOnclick() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var file = document.getElementById("imageFile").files[0];
        var file1 = document.getElementById("coverFile").files[0];
        formData.append("imageFile", file);
        formData.append("coverfile", file1);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("EditProfile","Default1")',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#GeneralSection').html(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $('#GeneralSection').html(error.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My last code was like yours. But I need to post all data together and replace response text with current content that `XHR`dont do this exactly for me. How can I add success or error page to XHR request?

Comment: If it is success then `UploadComplete` function gets called.you can write your code in that method. if uploads fails then `UploadFailed` function gets called

Comment: I copy/paste your code into my script section but it's steel sent null data to server side function. (success alert was shown in client side)

Comment: check updated answer..don't know why jquery is not taking file so i have used javascript

Comment: Thats problem again. All data and images file are null. :-(

Comment: I have tried..its working in here...can you post your latest code if possible

Comment: i have tried only for images it is working in your `ajax.beginform` but not sure how you are posting data to controller

Comment: if I post data using another ways, why formData in this scripts doesn't contain image files for me?

Comment: In your ajax method i have changed `ContentType:false` then image is coming in controller

Comment: Thanks for your helps @Nilesh. Do you test this operation with your script or mine?

Comment: I'm very confiused :-) It doesn't work for me, even without another data fields.

Comment: i have updated the answer...dont use jquery in that to append file

Comment: Your advices was very helpfull @Nilesh. Thanks :-) It's finally works without post another data. Just this line: `formData.append("imageFile", $("#imageFile").file);` doesn't work and must be replaced by `formData.append("imageFile", file);` Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks again :-) @Nilesh do you know why success function in script doesn't fired? (I need replaced some tag content with `responseText`)

Comment: I'll check and let you know

Comment: Since you are posting jsondata.Make your controller return type to `JsonResult` i.e  public `JsonResult EditProfile(...)` and if success   `return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` else return `return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Very very thank you Nilesh :-) I also add this code to add another data fields: `var username = document.getElementById("username").value;` and add this field to formData like this: `formData.append("username", username);`

Comment: Nilesh, i have tried in the exactly same way, but getting error. Even error.responseText doesn't print anything

Answer (score 4):

```
   <input type="file" id="picfile" name="picf" />
       <input type="text" id="txtName" style="width: 144px;" />
 $("#btncatsave").click(function () {
var Name = $("#txtName").val();
var formData = new FormData();
var totalFiles = document.getElementById("picfile").files.length;

                    var file = document.getElementById("picfile").files[0];
                    formData.append("FileUpload", file);
                    formData.append("Name", Name);

$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Category_Subcategory/Save_Category',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (msg) {

                                 alert(msg);

                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert("errror");
                    }
                });

});

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save_Category()
    {
      string Name=Request.Form[1]; 
      if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
         }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upload file through jquery using the iframe, I explained the same in my blog post, please follow the link to get the answer.

http://kaushikghosh12.blogspot.com/2014/02/ajax-fileupload-on-all-browsers.html