# Datatype for formdata at server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I would like to post a audio file to my server. Here is how I am trying to do:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fname', 'test.wav');
fd.append('data', soundBlob);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/test/testMethod',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
}).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
});
```

And at server side I have a method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void testMethod(??What datatype??  postedData)
{

}
```

What would be the datatype for `postedData` parameter? I tried with object and byte datatype. Any help would help.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but try to use HttpContext Class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Reading file input from a multipart/form-data POST: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7460231/4023446

Comment: There was same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629105/ajax-fileupload-jquery-formdata-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work by using `FormCollection` like:

```
[HttpPost]
public void testMethod(FormCollection frmCollection)
{
    Request.Files[0]  //-- this gives you the posted file
}
```