# How to Post file along with form data to MVC controller using Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post file along with other form data to MVC controller using jquery Ajax.

**jQuery Ajax call**

```
function SaveStundent () {
    var formData = new FormData();

    var file = document.getElementById("studImg").files[0];
    formData.append("studImg", file);

    var studentDetails = {
    Name: $('#txtName').val().trim()
    };

    formData.append("studentDetails", studentDetails);

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@(Url.Action("CreateStudent", "Student"))",          
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
            }
        });
}
```

**MVC Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateStudent(Student studentDetails)
{
// ...
}
```

**Student Model**

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Though I was able to get the file in the Request, the `studentDetails` parameter is always null in MVC controller.

Comment: How are you invoking the form submission? using submit button of the form or any other button outside the form?

Comment: Have u add Http.Post in action?

Comment: @TanvirArjel The jQuery method 'SaveStundent' will be called on 'Submit' button onclick event.

Comment: @beibeizhu yes I did. Sorry I missed to add the code

Comment: @Gopi Add your full `Student` model and input field you are using for the file upload in the form. please!

Comment: Sounds like your viewmodel passed as null because it doesn't match with the definition. Check these posts since you're passing with FormData object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629105/ajax-fileupload-jquery-formdata-in-asp-net-mvc & https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/581703/how-to-do-a-asp-net-mvc-ajax-form-post-with-multipart-form-data.

Comment: @Gopi: try to change your post data like : data: {studentDetails=studentDetails}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
function SaveStundent () {
    var formData = new FormData();

    var file = document.getElementById("studImg").files[0];
    formData.append("studImg", file);

    var Name= $('#txtName').val().trim()

    formData.append("Name", Name);

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@(Url.Action("CreateStudent", "Student"))",          
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
            }
        });
}
```

then change your action to get image as follow

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateStudent(Student studentDetails,HttpPostedFileBase studImg)
{
// ...
}
```

Working Code

```
<form id="frm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="studImg" id="studImg" />
    <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" />
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="SaveStundent()" />
</form>

<script>
    function SaveStundent () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var file = document.getElementById("studImg").files[0];
        formData.append("studImg", file);

        var Name = $('#txtName').val().trim()
        formData.append("Name", Name);

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@(Url.Action("CreateStudent", "Student"))",          
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            }
        });
    }
</script>

public ActionResult CreateStudent(string Name, HttpPostedFileBase studImg)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It did work for the form data but did not receive any file in studImg but Request.Files.Count was 1

Comment: insert cache: false to ajax parameters

Comment: It did not help

Comment: The answer does not have a `Student` parameter in the `CreateStudent` action method, which I think is important in the OP.

Comment: You don't need a separate parameter for the upload. Changes:
1. Student class - public HttpPostedFileBase studImg {get; set;} ...
2. CreateStudent method: public ActionResult CreateStudent(Student student) {...}
3. $.ajax({ url: '/home/CreateStudent', ...}

Everything else in the answer is correct. I tested this with MVC 5

Comment: will it work with mvc4.0 (visual studio 2012)?